# Animating bitmap ball - hit the wall and change direction effect

Tags: android

I am trying to animate a bitmap. I have a ball, and move it. When it reaches to the boundaries of the screen, i want it to change its direction like a mirror effect, i mean like this, think of the ball as the dots below, it comes down, hits the wall and changes its direction.

```
.          .
 .       .
  .    .
____._._______
```

Here is my code:

```
public class DrawShapes extends View{

Bitmap ball;
int x,y;

public DrawShapes(Context context) {
    super(context);
    ball=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ball);
    x=0;
    y=0;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {      
    super.onDraw(canvas);       

    if(x<canvas.getWidth())
        x+=5;
    else
        x-=5;
    if(y<canvas.getHeight())
        y+=5;
    else
        y-=5;
    canvas.drawBitmap(ball, x, y, new Paint());
    invalidate();

}
```

The problem is, after the ball reaches to a boundary, it keeps going and goes out of screen and never comes back. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: pure android or angengine ? and what is the wall's variable?

Comment: it is pure android, actually there is no wall, i just compare the x and y variables with the boundaries of the canvas as you see in if-else part

Comment: Are you sure the canvas is the same size as the screen? If the canvas is for some reason bigger than the screen it could cause this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm...if the canvas is larger than the screen, that would explain why it "goes out of the screen."

And it wouldn't come back because with your logic there, the ball should bounce back and forth between the same spot. Here's what I see:

```
canvas.width == 10

iteration1
x == 5
x += 5
x == 10

iteration2
x == 10
x -= 5
x == 5

iteration3
x == 5
x += 5
x == 10
```

Comment: yes you are right, thanks for both about the canvas size and telling my logic is faulty

Answer (score 1):

After it reaches the edge of the screen, it will move back onto the screen once, but then x/y will be < height/width again, causing it to move off the screen again straight away.

You should have a variable called something like `x_direction` and another for `y`, which changes (`x_direction = -x_direction`) if the ball is outside the boundary, and then doesn't change until another boundary is hit. Then move the ball each time depending on the direction variables. Hope I explained that ok.

Comment: thank you for your advise, i figured it out by keeping some boolean variables indicating the direction up,down,left and righr now it works